# Mobile apps statistics API

Tags: android, ios, mobile, statistics

I need to collect stats for my mobile apps.

I like flurry.com but I want to use my server and generate custom reports for my users.

Do you know if exists opensource API like flurry library?

Answer (score 1):

[Countly](http://count.ly/) is quite nice. It's built with Node.js (+ Express ) and MongoDB for data. However, I don't know how easy it would be to extend it for custom reports.

Comment: Thank you, it seems suitable for the purpose

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Google Analytics for Mobile](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/). It's not open source software but it is a free service.

**Update:** since OP wants to use his own server. As far as I'm aware there is no available analytics package for Android that comes as a software, which you could install on your server. So:

1. You could create your own client and server solution.
2. Use Mixpanel, which is similar to Google Analytics for Android, but it has a [data export API](http://mixpanel.com/api/docs/guides/api/v2). So you can pull this data from your server and process it. This is not a standalone solution, but it will give you features that you need. The client API has Event class, to which you can append your `Map<String, String>` of custom properties.

Comment: I need to store data on my server no on google server

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best bet would be to write your own library, as I've seen in a few other projects.

Make a virtual class. The first time it is instantiated it generates a string with a unique ID for the user.

Every other time it is instantiated it generates a unique ID to identify the session.

Make some methods to be called every time a meaningful event happens (e.g.: A method to be called every time a view is opened, or a button is clicked, or a event happens) which stores the data in a local database, or cookie.

Periodically send the cookie. This is the least resource-intensive method, and still it's very easy to implement.

Collect as much data as possible before trying to make meaningful conclusion, because if the sample is too small you will not understand much.

Store the data on a server so in the future you might improve your model according to the existing data.

Comment: Yes this is my last option. I'd like to use a common library.